# With SciPy dendrogram, can I change the linewidth?

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I'm making a big dendrogram using SciPy and in the resulting dendrogram the line thickness makes it hard to see detail.  I want to decrease the line thickness to make it easier to see and more MatLab like.  Any suggestions?

I'm doing:

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hicl
from pylab import savefig

distance = #distance matrix

links = hicl.linkage(distance,method='average')
pden = hicl.dendrogram(links,color_threshold=optcutoff[0], ...
       count_sort=True,no_labels=True)
savefig('foo.pdf')
```

And getting a result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbGRf.png).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the default linewidth before calling `dendrogram`.  For example:

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hicl
from pylab import savefig
import matplotlib


# Override the default linewidth.
matplotlib.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 0.5

distance = #distance matrix

links = hicl.linkage(distance,method='average')
pden = hicl.dendrogram(links,color_threshold=optcutoff[0], ...
       count_sort=True,no_labels=True)
savefig('foo.pdf')
```

See [*Customizing matplotlib*](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/customizing.html) for more information.

Comment: Can this be done w/o importing matplotlib separately from import pyplot?

Answer (score 17):

Matplotlib has a context manager now, which allows you to only override the default values temporarily, for that one plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

distance = #distance matrix
links = hierarchy.linkage(distance, method='average')

# Temporarily override the default line width:
with plt.rc_context({'lines.linewidth': 0.5}):
    pden = hierarchy.dendrogram(links, color_threshold=optcutoff[0], ...
                                count_sort=True, no_labels=True)
# linewidth is back to its default here...!
plt.savefig('foo.pdf')
```

See the [Matplotlib configuration API](http://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc_context) for more details.

Comment: This is amazingly useful in plenty of other contextes! Very neat.

Comment: This works only for linewidth, other styling options, like linestyle are disabled

Answer (score 0):

set dendrogram on existing axes than change its artists using `setp`. It allow changing all parameters, that won't work if `dendrogram` is sent to axes or won't work with `dendrogram` at all like `linestyle`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hicl
links = #linkage

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
hicl.dendrogram(links,ax=ax)
plt.setp(ax.collections,linewidth=3,linestyle=":", ...other line parameters...)
```